# Storage for iOS development

Tags: ios, core-data, storage, icloud

I have db which is kept in Core Data and I need to download full data from some storage. I don't want to write web server for this. Is there any way to store my full data for further downloading? Can I use `iCloud` for this? Or anything else? Thank you

Comment: Download what to where ?

Comment: It's impossible to tell what you're really asking.

Comment: for example, I have a db of dictionaries, just a little part of them. I want to load rest part from somewhere, rest part of these dictionary entries will be in other place, maybe it will some server or something else. But I don't want to create it because of no skills in this area. Is there a possibility to do anything without work of an other programmers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iCloud is connected to you personal Apple ID, so it would not be possible (or at least not its intended use) to allow others to download data from your iCloud account.

Have a look at [Parse](http://parse.com) or [Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/). One of them might be the solution you are looking for.